# Set Default Vendor Detail using import scenario

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to add more Vendor Detail into Stock Item and set it to default, [image]

Here what I archived, it's add new line but not set to default 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below steps for setting the default vendor through import scenario.

[Vendor Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yK8aD.png)

[Import Scenario-Field Mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99IeK.jpg)

[Stock Items Screen][3]